# MVVM Visibility property on Windows 8.1 not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-8.1

I have a button that is showing a grid with information and a button to close that grid. 
The code to show the grid by making the visibility property = Visible is working, but the code to collapse/hide the grid does not work.

Here's the sample XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridSubmittedOrderDetails" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="200" 
      MaxWidth="600" Visibility="{Binding OrderDetailsVisibility}"/>
```

the 'visibility' property in the viewmodel:

```
private Visibility orderDetailsVisibility;
public Visibility OrderDetailsVisibility
{
    get { return orderDetailsVisibility; }
    set
    {
        if (orderDetailsVisibility != value)
        {
             orderDetailsVisibility = value;
             Notify("OrderDetailsVisibility");
         }
     }
 }
```

The working code to show the grid:

```
var context = (SubmittedOrdersViewModel)DataContext;
context.OrderDetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

The code that's supposed to hide the grid, but doesn't:

```
var context = (SubmittedOrdersViewModel)DataContext;
context.OrderDetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

To whoever can figure out the mystery behind it, thank you. :)

Comment: Code looks fine. Does both button resides under same parent (i.e. both have same DataContext)? Aren't you explicitly assigning DataContext to both buttons?

Comment: On a side note: Don't put UI related code into your ViewModel. The purpose of ViewModel is to separate UI related code from your business logic/ViewModel. The `Visibility` class is a UI related class and may not be available in all UI frameworks (i.e. what would you do if you make a console application or ASP.NET MVC Website? Usually you would make it bool and use a converter like `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks fine. Possibly your viewmodel is not in the DataContext of grid.
Easy approach would be start application in debug mode and look in "output" window and confirm that your binding is working fine.

Output windows shows all binding failures.

Optionally, you can also put a breakpoint in `OrderDetailsVisibility` getter to see what value it's returning, and also confirm that it been used by your grid.

Comment: Thank you for helping me figure this out! True enough (I just didn't include the code here), I had actually assigned a different DataContext to the gridSubmittedOrderDetails (which is just a part of a page) before the part that makes them visible, when in fact the Visibility property was coming from the page's separate ViewModel itself. Thanks again!